# Как убрать метку @Deprecated с класса?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, color

Пишу код в IIDEA. Я что-то такое нажал и метод Color теперь перечёркнутый. Подскажите как всё вернуть назад?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

такая штука:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: IIDEA показывает таким образом все нежелательные методы, это как правило старые методы, которые давно переписали и имеют лучший функционал, но так как кто-то их предыдущую версию использует в старых программах, их не удалили, а просто таким образом показывают что их лучше не использовать. Color вряд ли сейчас является нежелательным, возможно ты случайно его добавил туда сам, гугли в этом направлении

Comment: Насчёт `String`, если вы уже сняли с класса метку @Deprecated, попробуйте перезапустить IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl + ЛКМ по слову "Color". Затем курсор на имя класса, Alt + Enter и нажимаем на подсвеченную синим кнопку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ещё такая проблема. эта байда у меня теперь во всех проектах. и перечёркнутый колор находится в выпадающем списке. приходится каждый раз отменять её. по ходу это глобально я где-то жмякнул. что теперь делать не знаю.

Comment: ошибся. String перечёркнут теперь

Comment: Я сейчас проверил, да, метка распространяется на все проекты, так же, как и снятие метки.

Comment: У меня и String и Color перечёркнуты в самом выпадающем списке. как в нём отмену сделать? скрин я бросил в вопрос